# How multidimensional array looks like with more than 2 dimensions?

Tags: c++

I know how it looks with 2 dimensions:

```
int myArray[][4] = {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 2, 3 }
};

int myArray[2][4] = { 1,2,3,4,  5,6,7,8 };

// So I've got now 2 arrays with 4 elements max.
```

But how looks it:

```
int myArray[][4][5][6];
int myArrayOther[][4][5][6][7]; // or it
```

I can't imagine it in my brain.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks" ? How its stored ? Or do you simply want to visualize it in space ?

Comment: A 3d array is a cube ... for the other ones you can only use your creative imagination

Comment: Tempted to make an ASCII art cube.

Comment: @AshRj - I want to visualize it in space.

Comment: visualizing N dimensions for N larger than 3 is always challenging. And not specific to C++.

Comment: @The_Cartographer, the space you mean is 3 dimensional. Lets think like this, when a 4 dimensional creature comes into our world we can see only its 3D "shadow"

Comment: If you want to be rigorous, C++ doesn't support arrays of more than one dimension.  `int myArray[2][4];` defines an array[2] of array[4] of int.  Adding extra dimensions just does the same thing: `int array[2][3][4]` is an array which contains 2 arrays, each of which contains 3 arrays, each of which contains 4 int.  It's just plain, ordinary nesting.

Comment: @The Space is only 3 dimensions. Imagine a ball with colour, flavour, and position, varying over time. That's 6 dimensions.

Comment: Then this should be on [math.se] if at all this is answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just continue with the nesting:

```
int array[4][3][2] = {
    { {  1,  2 }, {  3,  4 }, {  5,  6 } },
    { {  7,  8 }, {  9, 10 }, { 11, 12 } },
    { { 13, 14 }, { 15, 16 }, { 17, 18 } },
    { { 19, 20 }, { 21, 22 }, { 23, 24 } }
};
```

And so on

Comment: Thats not what the OP was asking.